# How to add to top of collection/remove from bottom of collection (Mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose, and I trying to both add to the top of a collection and remove from the bottom of the collection.  I know that I can get around this by storing all of this in an array (then use push and pop), but to me, it seems like that just adds another unnecessary layer.

By default, removing is from the beginning and adding adds the entry to the end.  Is there some way to add to the front of a collection and remove from the end?

Comment: And what exactly you what to achieve with that? Normally you would add a timestamp to your documents and query the db by the timestamp. I don't think there's a bettter way.

Answer (score 1):

Documents in a collection are not ordered, therefore there is no "top", "bottom", "front" or "back" to operate on. Adding, removing or updating a document can change the order of other documents.

To have documents in an order, add a field and sort by that field when querying.